# MenuTabs not showing up in Ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid

I'm just trying to get the columns menu tab to show up in Ag-Grid. Nothing complicated. I'd like to have the general tab and the columns tab, like in the demo [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/)

When I set nothing, only the general tab shows up. If I set general and columns, only general shows up. If I set only columns, I get a weird blank bar.

This is with general and columns set:
[image: General and columns tab set]

Code (in gridOptions - note that I'm using CoffeeScript)

```
defaultColDef:
  sortable: true
  resizable: true
  menuTabs: ['generalMenuTab', 'columnsMenuTab']
```

No errors reported in console. Using Vue.js if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MenuTabs are not fully supported on the material theme, which I was using. I've since switched to Balham and now have the menu tabs I want.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using `getMainMenuItems` callback instead of `menuTabs`

```
var gridOptions = {
    sortable: true
    resizable: true
    getMainMenuItems: () => {
     return ['generalMenuTab', 'columnsMenuTab']
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately - ended up with this result: http://snappyimages.nextwavesrl.netdna-cdn.com/img/7d3f56f2b5d848f71c39e236e0bff928.png

Comment: can you share your gridOptions code just to verify if anyother code is causing this issue

Comment: Did you try below line gridOptions: getMainMenuItems: () => {
     return ['generalMenuTab', 'columnsMenuTab']
    }

Comment: Yes, I took it out because it wasn't working. I get the following error in the browser console: "unknown menu item type columnsMenuTab" (same for generalMenuTab)